# Change src and id values for img inside parent div - pure JS

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, src

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeqPN.png)

I need to change src = "images/3d.jpg" and id = "test1-image" in img tag with other values "images/2d.jpg" and "cloned-test1-image".

I tried to do this:

```
var slikica = document.getElementById(cloned-test1);
slikica.setAttribute('src', images/2d.jpg);
```

But it will add src tag to my parent div instead of chaning src value of img.

Comment: Please give exact code. This is completely wrong.

Comment: I have div (id="cloned-test1") and inside this div there is a img. I need to change id and src of this img. Now it's id is test1-image but it should have id clone-test1-image. When I found how to do this it will be easy to change src, but I don't know how to access this img inside div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imageParent = document.getElementById('cloned-test1');
var image = imageParent.querySelector('img')
image.id = '"clone-test1-image';
image.src = 'images/2d.jpg';
// if you want to change the parent id too
imageParent.id = 'my-new-parent-id';
```

You need to select the child from the parent element that you queried, you can do this in numerous ways like `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector` or `getElementsByClassName` you can change the id directly by the property. The only difference is that it only searches through ancestors of the given node. That the same as `document` but document is the webpage so you query over everthing.

Comment: I found this earlier and it works, but I also need to change this id ('test1-image') to 'clone-test1-image'. This is why I can't use getElementById('test1-image').

Comment: That is not correct, you simply do the same as you did for src. just `slikica.id =  'clone-test1-image'` javascript has the object reference stored as long as you have the `slikica` variable you can change everything with it ;)

Comment: If I do it like this, it will change id of div, not id of img. Let's start from beginning - I have div which has id="cloned-test1", inside this div there is a img which has id="test1-image"...First I need to do is to change id of this image to have name "clone-test1-image", then I need to change its source. With all above given examples I am changing id and src of div, not id and src of img which I need to do.

Comment: I'll update the answer for you to give you a working code pice for your situation. Just make sure to give a more clear question the next time around ;)

Comment: I found way to change it using childNodes, but your solution is better and it works for me. querySelector was something which I didn't see or use earlier. Thank you!